How to Load External HyperLogLog into Redshift
Does anyone know whether it is possible to generate hyperloglogs in external programs like Spark or PrestoDB and then import the hyperloglogs directly into redshift and have Redshift properly treat it as a hyperloglog column?
I have been digging on internet and initial attempts have not worked because of the difference in formats in how one system prints out the hyperloglog and how Redshift expects the input especially since Redshift represents sparse hlls as json and dense as Base64-encoded. I've seen almost no one discussing trying this, so shot in the dark to see if someone has a solution.
